# Populate a custom list depending on the chosen dialog option

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm having a problem populating a  custom list. When the app is on create it populates de the list with the default elements correctly. However, when i go to the settings dialog, I have a radio group that allows me choosing which array will be used to populate the list, but i can't call the populatelistview custom class from the dialog, because doesn't allow me using "this" as an input, because since it's in the dialog it doesn't accept it as context. This is my populatelistview class:

```
 class populateListView extends ArrayAdapter <String>
{
    Context context;
    String [] times;
    String [] runtimes;

    populateListView(Context c,String [] tms, String [] rts)
    {
        super(c, R.layout.seizure_list2,R.id.firstLine,tms);
        this.context=c;
        this.runtimes=rts;
        this.times = tms;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seizure_list2,parent,false);
        TextView runtime_text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        TextView time_text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);

        time_text.setText(times[position]);
        runtime_text.setText(runtimes[position]);
        return row;


    }
}
```

This is the line that is causing troubles in the dialog :

```
adapter = new populateListView(this, all_times_array, all_runtimes_array);
```

And finally, this is my dialog with the radio group:

`   public void dialog_filter() {

```
    final String[] grpname = {"Today", "This Month", "This Year", "All time"};

    AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //alt_bld.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    alt_bld.setTitle("See reports from ...");
    alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(grpname, -1, new DialogInterface
            .OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            time_filter = item;
            System.out.println(time_filter);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    grpname[item] + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            switch (time_filter) {


                case 3:
                    //adapter = new populateListView(this, all_times_array, all_runtimes_array);
                    bannertext = "Total seizures:" + " " + total_seizures;
                    banner.setText(bannertext);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                    break;

                case 0:
                    // adapter = new populateListView(this, today_times_array, today_runtimes_array);
                    bannertext = "Today seizures:" + " " + today_seizures;
                    banner.setText(bannertext);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;

                case 1:
                   // adapter = new populateListView(this, month_times_array, month_runtimes_array);
                    bannertext = "Month seizures:" + " " + month_seizures;
                    banner.setText(bannertext);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;
                case 2:
                  //  adapter = new populateListView(this, year_times_array, year_runtimes_array);
                    bannertext = "Year seizures:" + " " + year_seizures;
                    banner.setText(bannertext);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;


            }


            dialog.dismiss();
        }
            }


    );
    AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line of code for creating adapter inside onclick method to like this

```
adapter = adapter = new populateListView(YourActivityName.this, all_times_array, all_runtimes_array);
```

Comment: I'm getting nullpointer exception with this method. During OnCreate I'm using this method exactly without any problems

Comment: When I call this:

populateListView(YourActivityName.this, all_times_array, all_runtimes_array);

Comment: have you written your activity name in place of "YourActivityName" in code?

Comment: Yes, and I have realised that the problems come from the arrays, because they are null. In the main activity they are not. How can i pass the values into the dialog?

Comment: assign your array to adapter in switch case for a particular selection

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter requires the first input to be an instance of `Context`. Since `Dialog` does not extend from `Context`, you can not instantiate your adapter using `this`. You can however call `getContext()` from your dialog and pass that instead.

Comment: I can't find this method, only getAppliCationContext() or getBaseContext()